# Fixed background distortion with mobile viewport meta

Tags: android, html, css, background, background-image

When i'm using fixed background with mobile vieport, i have strange background distortion.

Code:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{background:url(1.jpg) fixed;}
</style>

<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Results:

[image: With mobile vieport and fixed background]
[image: Without mobile vieport or fixed background]

I'm using chrome in android 6 phone.

Anyone know how to fix this problem? I really want to use fixed repeated backgrounds :)

Comment: use "background-size:cover"

Comment: distortion still exists